# Maximize equation with summation.

Tags: derivatives, optimization, summation

Given:

$$l(\lambda) = -\lambda n + log(\lambda) \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \sum_{i=1}^n log(x_i!)$$

Verify that this function $l(\lambda)$ is maximized by $\bar{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

---

Taking the derivative, I got

$$0 = -n + \frac{n}{\lambda}$$
$$0 = n\left(\frac{1}{\lambda} - 1\right)$$

But I'm not sure exactly how to proceed at this point or even if I took the derivative properly. Could I please have some guidance?

Comment: However did you get $\frac{n}{\lambda}$?

Comment: You got any additional information about the $x_i$? Your derivative seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Gaffney some incompetent researching of the subject I guess :/

Comment: Don't research.  Just take the derivative.

Comment: @Adam this is statistics related so $x_i$ is a number in a data set.

Comment: So are the $x_i > 0 $? Otherwhise $log(x_i !) $ is not definied for example.

Comment: @Adam correct. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Gaffney would it just be $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\lambda}$, treating the summation as a constant?

Comment: I think it should be $\tilde{x}= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Comment: @Adam I was thinking the same because the answer to the previous question was that value. I think it was a typo on the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$ l'(\lambda) = -n + \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i.$$

From $l'(\lambda)=0$ you get
 $\lambda = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$  is an extreme point.

Further you have

$$ l''(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i ) = - \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i }{ (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2} < 0 $$
since $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i >0$. Which is sufficent to show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is a maxima.